# wrong output for python program in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

```
print("How many kms do you want to convert?");

kms = input();

miles = float(kms) / 1.60934;

print("OK converted data is :" + round(miles, 2));
```

> I want to execute this python program in visual studio 2015 but when I enter a integer it returns nothing and when I enter a float number it returns this error:
>   [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRx4w.png)
>
> Can you please correct my code?

Comment: Show requirements, relevant code, output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelButscher, the title could use some improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was the type of the round(miles, 2)

```
print("How many kms do you want to convert?")

kms = input()

miles = float(kms) / 1.60934

print("OK converted data is :" + str(round(miles, 2)))
```

this works for me, and about the semicolons, I don't know well about it(So do whatever you want)

And the problem was, that integer types and string types couldn't join via "+", so I added str() to convert it to string!

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can not mix types in most cases. `round` returns a number, so you need to convert it to a string. For the future you should try to use pythons [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). For example: `print(f"OK converted data is {round(miles, 2)}")`. Note the `f` in front of the string. Then you can skip the converting.